# Проблемы Laravel JWT токена

Tags: laravel, jwt

Вызывает определенный вопрос то, почему библиотека **tymondesigns/jwt-auth** не выдает refresh токен.
Основная идея JWT токена ведь состоит в том, что у нас **access** токен, живущий условные 2-3 минуты. И есть **refresh** токен (бегающий в **httpOnly**) куки.
И имею оба, мы можем получать новый токен каждый раз, пока у нас жив **refresh** токен.
Но библиотека, указанная ранее, нам на:

```
auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))
```

генерирует нам только один токен. Который, по всей видимости, сам себе и **access**, и **refresh** токен.
Делая всё по доке, мы получаем, что **/login** **endpoint** у нас не закрыть jwt защитой, а **logout**, **refresh** **endpoits** у нас им закываются.
И тут вырисовывается ряд больших вопросов, касающийся всей тематики, и которым нет ответа в просторах интернета:

1. На сколько это соответствует самой идее JWT, иметь только 1 токен, который сразу и **access** и **refresh**?
2. На сколько безопасно выставлять такому токену срок жизни неделю, две? Учитывая то, что он в веб-приложении будет жить в http куке? (не **httpOnly**).
3. К каким последствиям можем привести снятие **jwt guard**'a с **/refresh endpoint**?
4. Развивая вопрос с номером 3, приведу пример следующее: библиотека имеет конфигурации: **JWT_TTL** и **JWT_REFRESH_TTL**. Следовательно, первая в минутах нам указывает, сколько наш генерируем токен будет жить. Второй - в минутах, сколько времени мы сможем рефрешить наш  полученный токен. И получаем такой расклад: если наш **JWT_TTL** истёк, то к **/refresh** мы достучаться не можем. НО! Если мы снимаем jwt защиту с **/refresh**, то мы можем спокойно рефрешить наши токены до тех пор, пока **JWT_REFRESH_TTL** не истечёт.
5. Следовательно, вопрос для п.4 следующий: зачем нам вообще нужен **JWT_REFRESH_TTL**, и **/refresh**, если мы можем выставить для нашего **access** токена долго время, и не беспокоиться, что нам что-то нужно рефрешить? И зачем нам этот рефреш нужен, если мы им не можем воспользоваться им по истечении **access** токена?

Comment: Почему вы эти вопросы бросаете в воздух, вместо того чтобы задать их автору пакета _tymondesigns/jwt-auth_? И у него есть форк (_PHP-Open-Source-Saver/jwt-auth_) над которым работа продолжается, ибо оригинал не обновлялся

Comment: @InDevX я, как и вы являемся участниками сообщества программистов. Кто-то в профессии по времени больше, кто-то меньше. Следовательно, найдутся люди, которые ранее уже задавались похожими вопросами, и нашли ответ на них. Следовательно, если у них на то возможность и желание, они поделятся своими наблюдениями и опытом относительно заданного вопроса. Если же нет, данный ресурс не возбраняет висеть таким вопросом до момента, пока найдётся человек, желающий поделиться своим опытом и знаниями с сообществом.

Comment: p.s. касательно автора библиотеки: если автор забросил свой столько популярный продукт, он не будет отвечать людям на такие вопросы. И вы это должны прекрасно понимать.

Comment: Практика показывает обратное, в 99% на такие вопросы никто не отвечает тут... Можете создать issue у пакета, там вероятность получить ответ намного больше. А касательно автора, раньше приходилось писать подобным на почту - ответ всегда получал